# C# sorting list by two dates

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list containing the following dates

```
03/05/2017
03/03/2017
03/04/2017
12/15/2016
12/20/2016
12/30/2016
```

I want to sort the list from oldest to newest for last 7 days and newest to oldest for last 90 days

The end result should look like this

```
03/03/2017
03/04/2017
03/05/2017
12/30/2016
12/20/2016
12/15/2016

FilteredList.OrderBy(x => ReportDate < DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7))
    .ThenBy(x => ReportDate < DateTime.Today.AddDays(-90))
```

Can this be done?

Comment: well, did you print the result of that linq query ? Did you get what you expected?

Comment: What about dates more than 90 days in the past?

Comment: Sorry typo I didn't calculate date correctly

Comment: @MatthewWatson It's really an open question [whether the past actually exists in any meaningful sense](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/32174), so I wouldn't worry about that issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach which might work is using a lookup:

```
var lastWeekOrBefore = FilteredList.ToLookup(x => x.ReportDate >= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7));
```

Now you have something like a `Dictionary<bool, IEnumerable<Report>>` which contains two elements, one group with `ReportDate` in last week and all others.

```
FilteredList = lastWeekOrBefore[true].OrderBy(x => x.ReportDate)
       .Concat(lastWeekOrBefore[false].OrderByDescending(x => x.ReportDate))
       .ToList();
```

Comment: Great answer, I do have a gripe with the use of anonymous types in C# though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var FilteredList = new List<DateTime>
{
    new DateTime(2017,3,3),
    new DateTime(2016,12,20),
    new DateTime(2017,3,5),
    new DateTime(2016,12,30),
    new DateTime(2017,3,4),
    new DateTime(2016,12,15)
};

var result = FilteredList.OrderByDescending(x => x > DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7)? 1 : 0)
    .ThenBy(x => x < DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7)
        ? -x.Ticks
        : x.Ticks);

foreach (var i in result)
    Console.WriteLine(i);

Console.ReadKey();
```

Result:

```
3/3/2017 12:00:00 AM
3/4/2017 12:00:00 AM
3/5/2017 12:00:00 AM
12/30/2016 12:00:00 AM
12/20/2016 12:00:00 AM
12/15/2016 12:00:00 AM
```